# A dismissed presented view controller keeps responding to NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a view controller that is modally presented, and I add it as an observer for a notification. After I dismiss the view controller, it keeps responding to the notification. Is this normal? If so, what should be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should unregister the view controller from notification centre.

The good way to do that is do the register to notification in `viewDidAppear` method and unregister in `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: If I don't unregister, does the view controller get retained?

Comment: No it doesn't. The common approaches is to add the removeObserver... to dealloc method. So just before the class is deallocated the observer will be removed. The reason you want to remove the observer from notification is that you want to prevent further messages from being sent.

Comment: I want to ask another question, but I guess I can't. Can you tell me how to dismiss a view controller programmatically?

Comment: This is how I presented my view controller:    `UINavigationController *nc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];`
   ` [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];`
And this is how I dismissed.    `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
If you could help, that would be so much help!

Comment: Yes this is how you do it.

Comment: Maybe there is something which keep it live. You have a navigation controller and you must have some root view controller added to it so maybe the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forget to remove observer after dismissing and your view controller is retained somewhere:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: If I don't remove as observer does it get retained?

Comment: NSNotificationCenter doesn't retain objects, it seems to retained somewhere else